# How to add ActionListeners to a modal JDialog?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, modal-dialog, actionlistener

I wanted to create a `JDialog` which responds to mouse and key actions. The dialog holds a jTable where I want him to select a record. He should be able to select it by double click or by pressing a key (e.g. "2").

So I started by this:

```
public showDialog(TableModel model) {
    super(new JFrame(), "Please select a record..."); 
    table = new JTable(model);

    //add JTable with ScrollPane
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, Math.min(table.getPreferredSize().height+60, 800)));
    scrollPane.getViewport().add(table);
    add(scrollPane);

    //display
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    toFront();
    pack();
    setVisible(true);

    //mouse
    table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            System.out.println("clicked");
        }
    });

    //keys
    table.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {}

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {}

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            System.out.println(evt.getKeyChar() + " pressed");
        }
    });
}
```

This works flawlessly.

However if I do the same thing with the statement `setModal(true);`, the listeners stop working.

How can I make my JDialog modal without losing the functionality of my listeners?

Comment: what is this class? does it extends JDialog?

Comment: why don't show it to us? are there any other methods in that class?

Comment: i don't since i think it's not necessary to post everything. and yeah it does own other methods..

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov so you downvoted my question because of that now or what?

Comment: because you don't show enough code

Comment: the only thing i did not show was the class around it with all the imports and another method, which simply processes the user's chosen record. So you can't tell me, that this would have been useful here..

Comment: @Romano Mächler this `1)` isn't real question, `2)` don't to use MouseListener and KeyListener for JTable, without special reason as color highlighter is e.i., not your deal, `3)` for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, with intentions to removing noises from rest of your code, `4)` agree with down_voter, `5)` otherwise you'll get an answers don't touching your issue

Comment: i try my best, did also already read the SSCCE.. don't really know how i might have better asked my question. maybe you can give me some further advices?

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution: when the JDialog is modal, then setVisible() blocks the current thread, i.e. the Dialog's Constructor. Thus the Listeners are never added (actually only when the Dialog is closed). Therefore no events.

Solution: set 'setVisible(true);' to the end of the CTOR

BTW you should not to modal locking in the CTOR, having an extra method like 'void showTheDialog();' is better.
If you had done this from the beginning, the listeners would have been there and everything would have worked ;-)
Edit: Or use something like a Factory method, that's even better.

BTW PLEASE PLEASE stick to naming conventions, it took me 10 seconds to figure out that with 'public showDialog(TableModel model) {' you had not forgotten the method return type but that this would actually have been the CTOR itself :-)

Comment: not true this isn't major issue, I think valid only for JOptionPane, but about shot to the dark, maybe your right

Comment: did set it now to the end. didn't pay out though. my problem is that i want to run a modal dialog right after the start. so until the user doesn't select anything from my records, the program won't run any further. so yeah, it's my CTOR ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think this can cause a problem:

```
super(new JFrame(), "Please select a record...");
```

Why are you creating a new `JFrame`, you have to specify an existing one.

Btw, you should call `super` in constructor of your class which extends `JDialog`, not in some other method.

Comment: No its not. But I definitely don't know why does he use that at all.

Answer (score 2):

- remove `MouseListener` is useless for your goal
- remove `KeyListener` is useless for your goal
- set proper [ListSelectionMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection) to `JTable`
- add [ListSelectionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) to `JTable`

Comment: +1 for that, did not know about the ListSelectioListener. will try it out if this solves my problem :) mKorbel strikes again? :D

Comment: another thing about the listeners is the following: i implemented the key listener to make it confortable to select a row (pressing 3 = selects row #3). how do i approach this correctly? with keybindings?

Comment: `select a row (pressing 3 = selects row #3). how do i approach this correctly? with keybindings?`, yes exclusively (`delayed wiht swing Timer, because 15th. row is about two keyevents `1 is pressed` then `5is pressed`), but maybe is better to use built_in filtering and sorting, instead of jumping of rows from numpad :-)

Comment: better a safer could be invoking JOptionPane with JSpinner (range is number of rows from JTable), then on OK button is pressed only to move selection to the returned row, methos is `table.changeSelection(intRow, colum, false, false);` column value  could be 0 (zero)